# Django 1.10 error, 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I'm trying to build a user signup page for a Django project.

I have an app called **custom_user** in which the **models.py** file contains the following (apart from imports):

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, identifier, password, email, full_name, date_of_birth):
        user = self.model(
            identifier=identifier,
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            full_name=full_name,
            date_of_birth=date_of_birth
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user

    def create_superuser(self, identifier, password, email, full_name, date_of_birth):
        # Almost same as previous method.

class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    objects = CustomUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'identifier'
    identifier = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)

    email = models.EmailField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['full_name', 'email', 'date_of_birth']

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.full_name
    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.identifier
```

In another app called **sign_up**, the view for signing up looks as:

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            # Create the new user.
            manager = CustomUserManager()

            user = manager.create_user(
                form.cleaned_data['identifier'],
                form.cleaned_data['password'],
                form.cleaned_data['email'],
                form.cleaned_data['full_name'],
                form.cleaned_data['date_of_birth'],
            )

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('sign_up:user_created'))
    else:
        form = CreateUserForm()

    return render(request, 'sign_up/index.html', {'form': form})
```

The **views.py** file imports the `CreateUserForm` class (placed in **sign_up** directory's **forms.py**):

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from custom_user.models import CustomUser

class CreateUserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['identifier', 'password', 'email', 'full_name', 'date_of_birth']
```

... And finally the template used by the view contains:

```
<h1>Welcome to the signup page!</h1>

<form action="{% url 'sign_up:index' %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}
<input type="submit" value="Sign up" />
</form>
```

When the form is submitted (and `form.is_valid()` seems to return `True`), the error message **TypeError at /sign_up/ 'NoneType' object is not callable** displays instead of the **user_created** view.

Traceback:

> File
>   "/Users/carltiden/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py"
>   in inner
>     39.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "/Users/carltiden/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File
>   "/Users/carltiden/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File "/Users/carltiden/GitHub/a_project/a_project/sign_up/views.py" in
>   index
>     24.                 form.cleaned_data['date_of_birth'],
>
> File
>   "/Users/carltiden/GitHub/a_project/a_project/custom_user/models.py" in
>   create_user
>     15.             date_of_birth=date_of_birth
>
> Exception Type: TypeError at /sign_up/ Exception Value: 'NoneType'
>   object is not callable

(Line 15 is `date_of_birth=date_of_birth` line in actual code.) Why is this happening; what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not at all how you use managers. You never instantiate them yourself outside of the model definition; you access them via the model itself.

```
    if form.is_valid():
        user = CustomUser.objects.create_user(
            form.cleaned_data['identifier'],
            form.cleaned_data['password'],
            form.cleaned_data['email'],
            form.cleaned_data['full_name'],
            form.cleaned_data['date_of_birth'],
        )
```